# RAILS: Securing route to customer to prevent unauthorized access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a route `match "company/:company_id/edit_users"` which I'd like to lock down to the user who's currently logged in.

For example, the currently logged in user is associated with company ID of 1.

So the user should be able to visit `/company/1/edit_users` but shouldn't have access to `/company/2/edit_users`

How can I make this secure, and redirect to an 'Unauthorized Access' page if a user's try to access a page they don't have permission to view?

Comment: You can use cancan for authorization.

Comment: Is this the only link you want to secure or will be more? if this is the only one you don't need a Gem I can put some code here for it. If there are or will be more like this then you need Gem for it again I can suggest some. First I need to know the answer for this comment. Thanks.

Comment: This would be the only one.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up something like a `verify_access` method in your company controller (assuming that is where the route is processed) that you call as a `before_action` for the `edit_users` method. Put this near the top of the controller:

```
before_action :verify_access, :only => [:edit_users]
```

then define the method later as a private method, maybe something like this:

```
private
  def verfiy_access
    unless current_user.company.id == params[:id]
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have authority to access that page."
      redirect_to unauthorized_access_path
    end
  end
```

You'll need to customize this for your app and make sure it restricts access appropriately.

You could also expand the `before_action` to include other actions if needed:

```
before_action :verify_access, :only => [:edit_users, :update_users, :destroy_users]
```